# Play Framework : Having multiple controllers

Tags: spring, oop, design-patterns, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm building an application with 10-20 Models, ergo I would have 4x functions to perform CRUD operations. 


What is the best way to organize my code (mainly the Controller)? 
Should I have multiple controllers ?( If so on what bassis ?).
Or Should I be dumping all the functions in the same controller ?

Right now i have written 5 models, I'm using Spring-Data-Jpa so I have 5 repositories, each being injected in to the controller(I have only one controller) so the constructor looks clumsy so I fear the clumsiness when i have 10-20 repositories.

Comment: Yes, you should divide controller to smaller ones

Answer (score 1):

You should divide it into smaller ones. Business can demand 100 models from having 10-20 in no time - It is a good idea to start with extensible architecture than to re-factor later.

Separate controllers for functionally distinct modules is usually a good way - It allows you to implement  things which are specific to that specific module (e.g access control) in a better way.

You can also create a base controller which extends play controller and make all other controllers  extend that controller. Common code can go in that base controller - so may be inject the repository which every function needs in base controller and inject others in only that controller which needs it.